# Getting "Page not found" error in publishing website via Github

Tags: github, github-pages, blogdown

I am relatively a new user of R and it is my first post in StackOverflow, so please excuse me if I do not give the relevant information about my question :) My problem is basically about getting a "Page not found" error while publishing a website via Github. For the last couple of days, by using blogdown, I want to publish a personal website. I installed blogdown in my local R environment, designed a website, and then pushed the documents to the GitHub repository. In the GitHub settings section, it is written that my website is published, however when I try to enter the relevant website, I have always got the same problem - "page not found". I actually do not know the problem but you can find my repository in GitHub at https://github.com/muhammetozkaraca/muhammetozkaraca.github.io. The website address that I am trying to publish is https://muhammetozkaraca.github.io. Every kind of help is really appreciated. Thank you in beforehand.

Comment: I think you are looking for the GitHub guide on how to publish a website. Can you go through the operations described [in this GitHub guide](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#choosing-a-publishing-source) and detail where things go wrong by editing your question?

Comment: Thank you for the comment but it did not solve my problem. To elaborate, I designed the website by installing the "blogdown" on my local R environment, and then I uploaded the documents to Github. In the GitHub pages ->>> settings section, it is written that my website is already published in the https://muhammetozkaraca.github.io address, however, when I go to this website, I have "Page not found" error. My question is how to handle it as I tried nearly all troubleshooting in the web but it does not work. My repositor is also located in github --> muhammetozkaraca/muhammetozkaraca.github.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate the source repo from the website repo. Please see the **blogdown** book page at https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/github-pages.html for more info. In short, the repo https://github.com/muhammetozkaraca/muhammetozkaraca.github.io should only contain the *generated* website, i.e., it should only contain files that currently live in the `public/` directory. Currently, your `muhammetozkaraca.github.io` repo contains both the source (root directory) and the generated website (the `public/` directory).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. According to your suggestion, I deleted the repository and then only uploaded the public directory from my local environment to the new repository that I formed with the same name, muhammetozkaraca.github.io. Even though I do not get "404 not found" error for this time, the content is not the one that I designed with "blogdown". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The content of `public/` should be under the root directory of the repo. Move the files one level up. For example, `index.html` must be under the root directory.

Comment: Man, it just happened, and I really really really thank you. I do not know what to say. For couple of days, I just tried everything and now it now finally happened. I really really thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making repository inside your username only.
I would recommend building organization with `xyz` and make a repository with name `xyz.github.io`.
Add an `index.html` inside this repository.
Then it will be good to publish as you wanted.

RARE: 'Sometimes it takes 2-5 minutes to publish.'

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I saw a similar troubleshooting in the web but I really could not understand this. I mean, my GitHub name is xyz and in line with the tutorials that I reviewed in the web, I wrote xyz.github.io and I also have an index.html file in my public directory as well. So, what is the problem then?

Comment: You can create an organization by clicking [+] button on the top of website. Then whatever name you have given for `public` organization should be the name of repo made inside them. Hope this will clear your doubt.